# switch pro controllers bluetooth raspberry pi steam link not working

Tags: bluetooth, debian

I have the following setup:

- 3 switch pro controllers paired with blueman bluetooth
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- latest steam link to my windows 10 pc

as long as I have only 2 controllers connected, everything is working very smoothly, we can play games well. no lag no nothing.

But as soon as I try to connect the third controller (no matter the order), none of the other controllers work properly anymore, after a minute one of the controllers gets lost and does not work in game anymore.

Any idea on how to fix this and help me connect the third and 4th controller?

Comment: @andrew.46 migration would be nice!

Comment: Is the RPi on wifi or network cable? The RPi 4 has a module that does both wifi and Bluetooth. I would speculate that you are having too many connections. You can run `sudo btmon` to see if that gives you more debug information. Other experiments you could try is disabling the wifi. Using a separate Bluetooth USB dongle to connect the controllers to.

Comment: I am on cable LAN, no wifi. I tried a separate bt dongle, but anything connected there was not detected by steam link.